# How does this statement follow algebraically from the last one? (Algebraic eqations)

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I was reviewing some combinatorics notes and i found the following.

[image]

Can someone please help me understand how in the world does that statement follow from the monstrosity above it?

In case it matters, the task is attempting to solve a recurrence relation for its closed form.

Here is the full solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7aRM.jpg

Comment: Would you please provide more context and/or a link to the notes? Thanks. Anyway, you can plug $3$ different $n$ and solve a system of _linear_ equations.

Comment: I cant link you the notes since they are university property. The task is attempting to solve for the closed form of a recurrence relation using the characteristic equations method. We had 3 unknowns and 2 initial conditions, so the author decided to use the original relation in order to solve for one of the unknowns, leading to this eqation, which gives us b=-9.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin no i cannot, i have only 2 initial conditions and 3 unknowns.

Comment: Okay, then maybe just _the_ solution from the beginning? For me it's hard to say why $b=-9$ without solving the entire linear system. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the full solution.

Comment: Heh. It comes simple. $(x^2-6x+8)=0$ have roots $2,\,4$ thus the two other terms just $=0$. Then we cancel by $3^{n-2}\ne 0$. Thanks for the full solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111525/discussion-between-hristmar-and-alexey-burdin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $2^2 - 6 \cdot 2 + 8 = 0$, $4^2 - 6 \cdot 4 + 8 = 0$.

(Thanks @AlexeyBurdin for pointing out an oversight)